TypeScript Error: Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Response | undefined' in Playwright Test Script
I'm working on a Playwright test script in TypeScript and encountering the following error:
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Response | undefined'.ts(2322)

Here is the relevant portion of my code:
import { test, expect, Page, Browser, BrowserContext, Response } from '@playwright/test';
import { chromium } from 'playwright-extra';
import StealthPlugin from 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth';

// Use playwright-extra and apply stealth plugin
chromium.use(StealthPlugin());

// Configuration object
const config = {
    loginUrl: 'YOUR_LOGIN_URL',
    email: 'YOUR_EMAIL',
    password: 'YOUR_PASSWORD',
    pageTimeout: 60000, // 1 minute timeout for page actions
};

test('Admin Login', async () => {
    let browser: Browser | undefined;
    let context: BrowserContext | undefined;
    let page: Page | undefined;
    let loginResponse: Response | undefined;

    browser = await chromium.launch({ headless: false }) as unknown as Browser;
    context = await browser.newContext();
    page = await context.newPage();

    // Set up request interception to capture the login request and response
    await page.route('YOUR_LOGIN_API_URL', async (route) => {
        const response = await route.continue(); // Continue the request
        loginResponse = response; // Store the response
    });

    await page.goto(config.loginUrl);
    await page.evaluate(() => window.scrollBy(0, 400));

    await page.click('#cookiescript_accept'); // Handle cookie popup
    await page.fill('#admin-login-email', config.email);
    await page.fill('#admin-login-password', config.password);
    await page.click('button[type="submit"]');

    // Wait for the login response to be captured
    await page.waitForResponse('YOUR_LOGIN_API_URL', { timeout: config.pageTimeout });

    // Check if login was successful
    await expect(page).toHaveURL(/.*dashboard/);
    console.log('Successfully logged in and reached dashboard.');

    // Log the login response
    if (loginResponse) {
        const responseBody = await loginResponse.body();
        const responseText = await responseBody.text();
        const responseJSON = JSON.parse(responseText);
        console.log('Login response:', responseJSON);
    } else {
        console.log('Login response not found.');
    }

    await page.close();
    await context.close();
    await browser.close();
});

The error seems to be related to the line where I am assigning the response to loginResponse:
loginResponse = response; // Store the response

The error message indicates that TypeScript is expecting a Response or undefined, but void is being assigned.
I've verified that the route.continue() function returns a void, which is likely causing the issue. How can I modify the code to properly handle this and avoid the TypeScript error?

What are you actually trying to achieve? Seems like loginResponse is guaranteed to be falsey, so if (loginResponse) { is always false. Probably you want const loginResponse = await page.waitForResponse('YOUR_LOGIN_API_URL'), and it's guaranteed to be a Response since waitForResponse will throw if its predicate is never satisfied.

The original code doesn't make a lot of sense, and fixing the type error doesn't resolve the underlying problems. loginResponse can never be assigned to a response, so your if will never run.
Also, let Playwright manage the browser. Putting a ton of setup/teardown code in every test isn't maintainable.
Try something like:
test("Admin Login", async ({page}) => {
  await page.goto(config.loginUrl);
  await page.evaluate(() => window.scrollBy(0, 400));
  await page.click("#cookiescript_accept");
  await page.fill("#admin-login-email", config.email);
  await page.fill("#admin-login-password", config.password);
  const loginResponseP = page.waitForResponse(
    "YOUR_LOGIN_API_URL",
    {timeout: config.pageTimeout}
  );
  await page.click('button[type="submit"]');
  const loginResponse = await loginResponseP;
  await expect(page).toHaveURL(/dashboard/);
  const responseData = await loginResponse.json();

  // make this an assertion and remove the log
  console.log("Login response:", responseData);
});

In other words, loginResponse is the resolved value of page.waitForResponse, not route.continue(). You almost never need to use this fishy-looking pattern in JS:
let result;
addListener((_result) => {
  result = _result;
});
// ...
console.log(result);

Note that the response listener needs to be set before the click, otherwise there's a race condition if the response arrives too quickly.
Responses have a .json() method so you don't need to use JSON.parse().
/.*dashboard/ has pointless regex syntax: /dashboard/ is functionally identical, although you might want something more precise like /\/dashboard/.
Once you have this test working and you want to add more, consider breaking out a POM.
